# Why is Ubuntu sometimes ugly when I log in?

Tags: gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

Sometimes, maybe once every week or two, things look like this when I log in:

[image: screenshot]

When this happens, I log out and then back in and things look normal again:

[image: screenshot]

This happens in Ubuntu 10.04 on my ThinkPad X60 and my custom built desktop. It has only ever happened on the first log in after booting the computer.

What could cause something so intermittent?

Comment: Could be related to this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible that gnome-settings-daemon (which controls theming) crashes or fails to start on login. If you want to confirm this as the case, you can enable crash reporting and see if it crashes when you notice it. From there, you can send in your crash report so it will hopefully be fixed.

To do this, open /etc/default/apport and change "enabled=0" to "enabled=1". You'll want to open this file as root; in a terminal type `sudo nano /etc/default/apport` to accomplish this. Change the value, hit Ctrl-X to quit, and press Y to save. Reboot, and crash reporting will be running and you'll be able to send in the problem when it happens.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Now it should just be a waiting game...

Comment: Thanks! this happens to me also, I will be reporting this.

Comment: There is a bug reported for this for quite some time: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/574296