# Can I simulate a slow hard drive?

Tags: performance, troubleshooting, hard-drive

I have hunch that a certain [intermittent bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4075/why-is-ubuntu-sometimes-ugly-when-i-log-in) might only manifest itself when there is a slow disk read rate. Troubleshooting is difficult because I can't reliably reproduce it.

Short of simply gobbling IO with a high priority process, is there any way for me to simulate having a slow hard drive?

Comment: I remember seeing a command to tell harddrives to run at certain bus speeds. I'll see if I can dig it out.

Comment: `man hdparm` take a look at the -X option maybe? There are quite a few things in there you could use to slow down your drive, but some of them risk doing nasty things to the data!

Comment: Also, try mounting a network share as a folder (google is your friend), maybe even over wifi, if that is plausible.

Comment: This isn't a direct answer, but: if I had an intermittent bug like this, I would probably try running the process under Valgrind (if it was in a compiled language), because that would likely capture IO race conditions.

Comment: Are you talking about a bug in an application, or the kernel, or a device driver? Or you don't know at all? It might help if you explained more.

Comment: @poolie It's [this problem](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4075/why-is-ubuntu-sometimes-ugly-when-i-log-in). It stopped happening on one computer when I installed an SSD.

Comment: OK, I think it is highly likely to be [what Jacob said](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4075/4077#4077) on that bug, that `gnome-settings-daemon` is crashing, probably related to the timing of different components starting up.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [nbd](http://nbd.sourceforge.net/), the Network Block Device, and then rate limit access to it using say `trickle`.

```
sudo apt-get install nbd-client nbd-server trickle
```

Comment: +1 for a pretty cool solution. however, it's not a real test because you not going to the real hard disk device driver, which where the problem may lie.

Comment: I didn't think he was talking about a driver bug, but that was just an assumption.  Let's see.

Comment: Is it possible to add the actual command to this answer? At the moment you only show how to install the tools required :)

Answer (score 5):

```
# echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

That'll slow you down :)

It'll force you to read from disk, instead of taking
advantage of the cached page.

If you really wanted to get sophisticated you could do
something like fake a read error every nth time using 
the scsi fault injection framework.

http://scsifaultinjtst.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Note: This will only drop the caches once. Then it will immediately start caching again. You might wanna wrap that in a loop.

Comment: @Androbin I like that idea. You could even add a sleep interval to the loop. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Have a USB 1.1 hub? Or a slow SD card? They'll get you down to under 10mbps.

Comment: nice...not technical enough for the +1 but nice

Answer (score 3):

This is by no means a complete solution, but it may help in conjunction with other measures: There is an I/O scheduler much like a process scheduler, and it can be tweaked.

Most notably, you can actually choose amongst different schedulers:

```
~# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler 
noop anticipatory deadline [cfq] 
~# echo "deadline" > /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler
~# cat /sys/block/sda/queue/scheduler 
noop anticipatory [deadline] cfq 
~#
```

`deadline` may help you get more strongly reproducible results.

`noop`, as its name implies, is insanely dumb, and will enable you to wreck absolute havoc on I/O performance with little effort.

`anticipatory` and `cfq` both try to be smart about it, though `cfq` is generally the smarter of the two. (As I recall, `anticipatory` is actually the legacy scheduler from right before the kernel started supporting multiple schedulers.)

Answer (score 3):

You can use a Virtual Machine and throttle disk access ... here are some tips about how do it in Virtualbox 5.8. Limiting bandwidth for disk images https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html#storage-bandwidth-limit

Answer (score 2):

Apart from trying to slow down the hard drive itself, you could try using filesystem benchmarking tools such as [bonnie++](http://packages.ubuntu.com/bonnie++) which can cause a great deal of disk I/O.

```
sudo apt-get install bonnie++
```

Comment: As the question says, "Short of simply gobbling IO"....

Answer (score 2):

You could try running a copy of a large file, such as an iso of the Ubuntu install cd, and run it twice. That should slow your drive down quite a bit.

Comment: As the question says, "Short of simply gobbling IO"....

Answer (score 1):

I have recently figured out a setup where I've

- moved the directory to my **Google Drive**
- mounted it via the super-duper-slow client **`google-drive-ocamlfuse`**
- created a **symlink** from the original path to the new one

If **16 seconds latency** is not slow enough, you can just unplug your router.

For reference, here is the original use case, where I got the idea for this:
https://github.com/goavki/apertium-apy/pull/76#issuecomment-355007128

Answer (score 0):

Why not run `iotop` and see if the process that you are trying to debug is causing lots of disk reads/writes?

Comment: I think this answer is seen as unhelpful because the mere fact that the process is doing lots of IO may be already known, or not a problem in itself.  The issue is that there is some kind of timing-related bug in the way it handles those IOs.

Answer (score 0):

how about `make -j64`? in articles describing that new 200line performance patch, `make -j64` was a task eating a lot of computer resources

Comment: You should explain what that command actually does.

Comment: As the question says, "Short of simply gobbling IO"....