# How to use nbd to simulate slow disk to an existing data directory

Tags: mount

I have come across the following thread explaining on how to use nbd and tirckle to simulate slow disk. But, my question is little different and hence creating a new question.

[Can I simulate a slow hard drive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13590/can-i-simulate-a-slow-hard-drive)

Question:
My application is writing on to /var/data-dir and I would like to validate my application for slow disk by simulating slow disk to /var/data-dir. 
Challenge: the directory specified contains app data containing heartbeat, session info etc.. Hence, it's important for me to mount nbd on to /var/data-dir. How may I use nbd to simulate slow disk here? I need to update lot of configuration files if I will have to mount nbd onto different location. Henge, I would like to avoid nbd mounting to  different location.

Most of the example I have across for nbd are with new directory/location. Hence the question.

@Poolie

Thanks,
Dinesh