# Upgraded to Maverick; can't change theme

Tags: upgrade, themes

I just upgraded to Maverick, and now I can't change my theme except for the cursor and window border/decoration. I've just reinstalled the themes I want to use (Dust + Dust extra) successfully, and while the window border/decorations change properly when I select them, nothing else changes. The icon set doesn't change; gnome-panel doesn't change. I'm stuck on the fugly fallback theme - the one you see when you do `gksudo gedit` or something.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that this works fine when logged in as another user. I nuked ~/.gconf and started my customizations from scratch. There is probably a less drastic way to accomplish this.