# How to prevent ubuntu to change theme automatically

Tags: 10.10

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

Suddenly after restart my default theme turned into a theme like this, 
Every time i change the theme it gets changed into a custom theme like this
Can somebody tell me how can i find the cause of this problem
Thanks

[image: Desktop]

Comment: Hello, it's a known bug, duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme .

Answer (score 0):

A short sleep in /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-settings-daemon fixes it:

`Exec= bash -c "sleep 2; /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon"`

Also see: [Bug #574266](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-settings-daemon/+bug/574296)