# Theme doesn't work. Gnome looks bad

Tags: gnome, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

I reinstalled my Ubuntu box with 10.10 (after my dabbing of 11.04 turns out to be a futile experience). The box is clean. I install the typical packages (Google Chrome, Dropbox, build-essentials, ...).

However, now whenever I login into GNOME. The GNOME panels and decorations look weird. They don't like they have the ambience theme on. Even if I choose the Ambience theme of Ubuntu, the theme is not applied.

Currently my desktop looks very ugly. All I want is my default Ubuntu looks back.

Comment: Do you have an SSD or a really fast PC? Could be this bug: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme

Comment: I do have an SSD with i7. That is an interesting bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use another window manager, like emerald.

Type `sudo apt-get install emerald` to install the emerald window manager.

After installing it type `emerald --replace` to replace your current window manager.

I hope this helped you,
Daniel