# Theme changed by itself

Tags: compiz, themes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

All of a sudden by theme was changed to how some old Ubuntu version looks like & then I was returned to my theme except all icons, and right click context menus, and how nautilius looks. I think only panels have the same look like before, all others have changed.

Title bar was gone too. I run compiz and I fixed it by running `gtk-window-decorator –replace`

Last line in my `.xsession-errors` is

**(nautilus:1756): GConf-CRITICAL **: gconf_value_free: assertion `value != NULL' failed**

What should I do to fix it now? Setting it in the themes didn't do any good as if its files went missing.

[image]

Comment: is this an install of 11.04?

Comment: @Jorge Castro Thanks! I solved the problem from one of the other answers on that page. So what do I do with this question? Vote for close? @Evilphoenix Its a 10.10 install

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this problem several times and I don't know what's causing it... Restarting ***X*** may be a fix, but I'm not sure it's the best one ;)

Comment: Thanks but adding some lines and saving it as `.gtkrc-2.0` worked for me as a permanent solution http://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme/21324#21324