# Why is my theme switching to the classic and back again?

Tags: 10.10, gnome, gnome-settings-daemon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

Okay so my Ubuntu 10.10 32-bit desktop (moments after logging in) will revert back to the "classic" gray gnome theme. This is an easy but annoying fix, since I can (constantly :P) just open Appearance and it will change back, automatically. But even after that Nautilis and desktop-right click are still old and gray looking. Is there a fix to this problem; This is getting very annoying. (Note: Also, my icons are affected as well :(  )

Comment: And I'm hoping for a permanent fix, as well. Because i'm easily distracted by those things.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like a broken config file somewhere in your home directory. The easiest way would be to create a new user account and see if that fixes the problem. If it does, and you want your old account back, you can then try and figure out which file caused it.

Comment: Thanks. I think I will, but first I will need to back it up. I'm probably just going to switch to PinGuy, anyway. Also, this happened on my other PC which I recently updated (Ubuntu 10.10) and had the same exact problems. Probably just an impeding bug. I'll live with it, for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. It has affected many users since 10.04.

Pasting the following in a txt file and make the file executable allows you to run as a script on every startup gets rid of the problem.

sleep 5; ps -aef | grep gnome-settings-daemon | grep -v grep | awk '{ print $2 }' | xargs kill -9; sleep 2; gnome-settings-daemon; killall nautilus

Comment: Thanks Bro. I will do this. So I just, make it a text file and run it in Terminal?

Comment: Okay thanks made it executable and will run it. ;)