# dist-upgrade to natty set gnome theme to old gtk look

Tags: gnome, upgrade, gtk

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

On dist-upgrade to natty there was some message about gtk and the gnome look was set to the old gtk style.

How to check the cause of that?  I am not sure what to look for in /var/log/dist-upgrade

Could anyone give a hint please - ie. what packages are responsible for the theming?

Comment: trying the mentioned workarounds....

Answer (score 0):

Logging out and in again did it for this time...