# Why is my Unity theme going haywire?

Tags: unity, themes

I have this new problem, my unity theme falls back to some old gnome theme which makes the whole look and feel absolutely horrible.

Here is the screenshot right after login:
[image]

And after sometime, theme changes to this:

[image]

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: What does running `unity --replace` do?

Comment: it does nothing

Comment: Probably this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme

Comment: @Jorge that was referring to on boot - since the SSD was faster than the boot process. This happens halfway though - I suspect it's a bug.

Comment: @Jorge . THis is very similar to mine. However, I think I have found a dirty fix. I need to test before I post.

Comment: VirtualBox uses too much RAM in time and the theme "goes haywire". Give the VM more RAM and it shouldn't do this anymore.

Comment: @Andrei: I tried , but still have the same error. However, when I install it to my laptop, it runs perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that your system is changing your theme to one that uses the Faenza icons set. Check if you have any themes that use these icons on your system and if you don't want it, just remove it. That maybe will do the trick.

By the way, do you have something in `~/.themes` in your Home folder?

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by the answers @Jorge mentioned in [Desktop forgets theme?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme), from [TM's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/43043/725299), I adapted his idea into unity env with a simple modification:

I replaced '**gnome-settings-**' in his bash script with '**unity-settings-**', you know, just to change PID. And it worked!