# GTK Theme and icons fail to load

Tags: fonts, icons, gtk, ambiance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

I don't know if it's a recent update that's done this or not, but in my last three logins, the GTK theme, icons and Ubuntu fonts don't load. Instead, I'm presented with an unskinned GTK default, with GNOME icons and the default Sans font.

Any ideas what could be causing this?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme

Answer (score 0):

Go to appearance from system>preference menu
Select Theme tab. use to select your theme. IF there is not theme then install new gtk theme.(It's easy. just download and drag and drop on appearance instance). If it does not work then open terminal and type
metacity --replace

if any unwanted error message shows then please provide the errors to help you more.