# Can't change the icon theme

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, icons

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

I'm running Ubuntu 11.04 on Virtualbox and I cant' change the nautilus icons. I've followed a lot of tutorials... but nothing works. I can only see the icons I've choosen when I run `gksudo nautilus` but not when I'm a normal user any suggestions?

This is what it looks like when I'm a normal use:

[image]

This is how it should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Like **htorque** says it's duplicated. I've fix the icons problem with this answer: [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme/21324#21324)

> Create a text file. Write in it
>
> ```
> include "/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc"
> gtk-icon-theme-name = "ubuntu-mono-dark"
> ```
>
> and save it in your home folder under the name **.gtkrc-2.0** then
>   restart.
>
> If there are still elements wrong (for me it was the font), you need
>   to add this change to the file, google for a gtk tutorial for the
>   possible fine tunings.

Answer (score 0):

The icons are directly relevant to the theme that you have selected.
Run `gnome-appearance-properties` and choose the them you like.

If that doesn't help, run `users-admin` select your user, then press on "Advanced Setting".
Now move to "User Privileges" tab and make sure that the field **Administer my system** is clicked, after this select them again as described above.

Comment: Done it, but it doesn't work. Maybe the bug is related to this bug that I've already fix: http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/fix-ubuntu-linux-mint-theme-changing-to.html