# Stuck in classic mode?

Tags: 11.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 in the latest VirtualBox (as of today) on my XP host.
I ran it, and it told me on login that I didn't have a good enough computer to use the new "Unity" thing.
I logged on and everything went fine, it looked like 10.04.
I then logged on in classic mode, to see what it does, but now i can't find the setting to log on the way it was before, even when I selct Ubuntu (not classic) at logon
Thanks in advance

EDIT it looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install a new GTK theme engine, the default one for ubuntu is gtk2-engines-murrine

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2-engines-murrine
```

If it's already installed try reinstalling it.

Also check that you have the light-themes package installed

If they're both installed and a reinstall does nothing, you have to select theme using the Appearance menu item or install the gtk-chtheme package that will give you more control over what is being used by GTK

Answer (score 0):

Without 3D graphics support, the new interface won't run, especially in a virtual machine.
I heard you can still install and run the Unity 2D, which is a separate project, try installing it or get your 11.04 some 3D capable GPU. Installing on real HW would be my choice. VirtualBox guest additions might help too.

Comment: Sorry, i don't think I explained myself. I want it to look like 10.x, but it is stuck with the "panels" gray and looks like win2k