# ubuntu theme suddenly changed to default and it's not coming back!

Tags: unity, themes, window-decoration

I logged in to ubuntu as I always do and suddenly the theme changed from what I have chosen to the default one and when I try to bring it back, it's working, but not the way it's supposed to:

[image: ubuntu theme problem]

As you can see the `Window Border` of the normal sized window is what I want it to be but the fullscreen one is not(it's ubuntu's default!) and also it is the same about icons.
I hope there is someone who knows what my problem is!

- I tried the solutions in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/21305) but it didn't work.
- indicator applet keeps crashing when I log in

Comment: may be related to: http://askubuntu.com/q/21305

Comment: Cannot really understand what you what to achieve after the window is maximized. Do you want the window side border to stay the same? Do you want the titlebar to stay visible? And maybe others?

Comment: well I want the fullscreen window have the same style as a normal window!

Comment: The theme has changed as @Hamed has said. It is now a custom theme that was not created by the user but by the OS as the desktop loaded. Selecting another theme does not have any effect. when this happens to me, I shutdown and restart and I get my chosen theme back and the custom theme disappears from the Appearance utility.

Comment: @Hamed does the solution from the question Takkat linked help?

Comment: @Jorge naa it didn't.
but my guess would be it's because of appmenu indicator applet cuz it keeps crashing every time I log in.

Answer (score 2):

This is a known bug from 9.04 onwards but appears worse in 11.04.On webupd8.org a workaround fix was posted in the last 2 months. After installing 11.04 i have just had the same problem so I went and looked for the article. This describes a fix. I have used it on another machine and can confirm it works.

- [Fix Ubuntu / Linux Mint Theme Changing To A Classic, Windows-95-like Gray Theme](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/06/fix-ubuntu-linux-mint-theme-changing-to.html)

To summarize, the solution is to edit `/etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-settings-daemon.desktop` as root, and replace this line:

```
Exec=/usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon
```

With this line:

```
Exec=bash -c "sleep 5; /usr/lib/gnome-settings-daemon/gnome-settings-daemon"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a hosed gconf to me.  I had this issue once after removing some application menu items.  Probably a weird parsing error that hasn't been pinned down yet.  Just my 2 cents.

My solution was to start over...not a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try running the command `unity` it worked for me.