# After installing nautilus-open-terminal, my desktop looks ugly

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, desktop-environments

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

I installed `nautilus-open-terminal` package to Ubuntu 11.04 (installed in Virtual Box), and my ubuntu desktop looks old.  Please look at:

[image: screenshot]

How can I change it back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose it has nothing to do with the package installed.

Run

```
pkill -f gnome-settings-daemon
gnome-settings-daemon
```