# Changed look of Nautilus after update

Tags: nautilus

I am using Ubuntu 11.04. my `sources.list` is the default one, I have not change it. I just updated Nautilus package in Synaptic manager and after restart Nautilus looks like Gnome3 Nautilus with an ugly theme. System theme is still the default. I also can not right click in the desktop. How can I restore previous Nautilus and desktop. I am providing preview of Nautilus 
[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Desktop forgets theme?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

Comment: @JorgeCastro, I don't think so. From the position of the side pane, it looks more like GTK3/GNOME3 Nautilus (the real problem, it sounds like) being unable to use GTK2 Ambiance (secondary problem).

Comment: You're going to add more detail to your question on what exactly is going on, that doesn't even look like nautilus from 11.04.

Comment: PPAs are not stored in /etc/apt/sources.list, but in several files in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/. I'm sure you must have added some other repositories, because that's not the version from 11.04.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I am installing from local repo. it contains gnome3 updated packages too. I upgraded gnome3 in another pc and using those packages. how can i roll back nautilus upgrade?

Comment: you may try to find and download the .deb package of the needed version of Nautilus from here http://packages.ubuntu.com/ and then install it using command like `sudo dpkg -i nautilus.deb`

Comment: @shantanu - this is related to the gnome-settings-daemon. Have you tried following the suggestions in the linked question by Jorge?. Since you asked the question have you updated your installation and still reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1):

That "ugly theme" is the default GTK theme.

There are numerous fixes to be detailed but this is the best [answer](https://askubuntu.com/q/21305/46312) I know of.