# Nautilus losing theme

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

I'm new to Ubuntu, I install it yesterday and I'm loving the system.

But there is a problem with Nautilus and I have no idea on how to fix this. Nautilus randomly loses its Ambiance theme, becoming all gray with a strange look. The icons also disappear too.

Doing a logoff or rebooting the system fixes the problem, but it happens again after a while. It seems completely random and it's quite annoying.

The Ubuntu version is 11.10 64 bit.

- This is not [Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme) as it only affects Nautilus.

Comment: I think it's a different bug, this one just affects Nautilus.

Answer (score 8):

It's an annoying bug, reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nautilus/+bug/859723) (though I'm not 100% sure that this isn't a duplicate of the bug I was looking for).

As a workaround you can run this from a terminal:

```
killall nautilus ; (nautilus &)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the command works. At least I don't have to logout.

But, there is a way to fix the problem permanently?

Comment: @Dennis Probably the only permanent fix will be when the bug itself has been fixed. Everything else would just be a workaround.

Comment: @WarriorIng64 Ok so, I think I will wait for the update.

Comment: Didn't happen to me until I updated to the 3.0 Kernel, and had to restart.

Maybe that command can be run as a startup script?

Comment: Doesn't make any difference run the command in the startup, the bug is caused when an random application is closed. Btw, until now the bug isn't fixed yet...

Comment: Is this answer still up to date?

Comment: @RolandTaylor I'm not experiencing the bug anymore, because I stopped using the software that triggered it, but **if** the bug affects a user, the answer should still fix it. Note, the loss of theme only affects Nautilus (including the desktop), so it's not to be confused with the g-s-d crash that transforms our system theme into Windows 95. ;-)

Comment: @RolandTaylor Since two days this bug annoys me on Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit. The workaround works, though.

Answer (score 0):

With older versions of Ubuntu, this was typically caused by a crash of `gnome-settings-daemon`.  To fix it, I could press Alt+F2, gnome-settings-daemon, Enter.

I'd like to know if this workaround still works in Ubuntu 11.10.  (So far I haven't seen this happen to me.)

Comment: It's a different bug, g-s-d doesn't seem to crash in that case (at least nothing in /var/crash suggests it).

Answer (score 0):

If you use `nautilus -q` command in terminal. it will solve. you just have to do it every time it happens. And open any folder after that command