# All of my icons appear blank. How can I change them back?

Tags: unity, 11.10, icons

I installed the new 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot Ubuntu version, and I am very happy with it, but today I had a problem that I dont know how to solve.

The icons of the directories have changed, look at this:

[image: http://www.subirimagenes.com/imagen-pantallazodel20111-7066022.html]

As you can see, the icons have white papers, and not their original one.

Comment: Did you install a theme? That doesn't look like any of the default themes.

Comment: This looks like the fallback theme called 'Raleigh'. Possibly a duplicate of: http://askubuntu.com/questions/21305

Comment: nope, i didnt do anything. I just turn on my pc and it changed alone.

Comment: Have you updated 11.10. I also had this problem a week ago. Updated with the official repository updates and after rebooting it was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is to install the drivers for your graphic card. I had the same problem and now it is fixed.

Answer (score -1):

I have a Nvidia GeForce GTX260 and I solved installing the reccomended video driver.