# Ubuntu forgets theme and reverts to default

Tags: system, appearance

My documents and folders and all other files have turned into a white paper and the machine and folder menu have the old windows 1990 layout which is very annoying, and I'd like to change it back to the normal. They work just the same as before but they look very bad. It came after a friend of mine clicked the "close computer" button (the button you also turn the computer on with) on the keyboard and then he clicked "turn off/shut down" in the menu that popped - which shouldn't do anything, and this was exactly what he did. Then when I wanted to turn on the computer again I should choose between some system layouts, which I think it was. I chose the most top and from that time on the appearance of files are awful. I don't know how to get back to that menu to switch system layout - been browsing the net for ages and tried closing the computer down like my friend did - nothing works.

Anyone have an idea what to do?

[image]

Comment: By the looks of it something is wrong with your themes, but a screenshot would be better.

Comment: What is Windows 1990? The first Windows after 3.11 was 95.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Desktop forgets theme?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

Comment: I added a screen shot to the question. (new to this web page).     To Jorge: It doesn't appear the same way as that. And to enzotib: It just looks white and ugly I don't know what kind of windows version that it precisely looks like. Just remember the old computers I used looked similiar.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are getting bumped back to some (ugly) default settings, probably because of some settings manager not working. You could try running in a terminal `killall gnome-settings-daemon`, then `gnome-settings-daemon&`. (You should be fine to close the terminal, even if it is still giving you more messages. The gnome-settings-daemon program should continue to run, and hopefully your theme will automatically be applied).

Comment: Thx for the answer but it didn't work out. Sometimes the theme falls back to normal again and those commands turned it back to ugly :( It seems to be switching now and then for some wierd reason.

Comment: If you don't close the terminal, what kind of messages does it give, especially when the theme changes?

Comment: [1] 2149
mortenfc@mortenfc-HP-Pavilion-dv6-Notebook-PC:~$ XIO:  fatal IO error 11 (Resource temporarily unavailable) on X server "HT000
rc_cA"
      after 51 requests (51 known processed) with 0 events remaining.

(gnome-settings-daemon:2149): GnomeDesktop-WARNING **: GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE helper quit unexpectedly

** (gnome-settings-daemon:2149): WARNING **: You can only run one xsettings manager at a time; exiting

** (gnome-settings-daemon:2149): WARNING **: Unable to start xsettings manager: Could not initialize xsettings manager.

Comment: ** (gnome-settings-daemon:2149): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down

Comment: @MortenFjordChristensen I would edit your question and add the error messages to it.

Answer (score -1):

its a theme issue, switch your theme to Ubuntu defaults first. I was running mine in GNome Classic UI. Here's what I did:

1. Log-out, Select Unity as your UI,then log-in
   Hopefully your folders are back to normal once you logged-in.
2. Log-out, Select GNOME Classic. then log-in.

*if your using UNITY already, try doing it in reverse. I can't replicate the error so I can't test if it would work. Hope this helps