# Odd theme problem in 11.10

Tags: themes, icons, gtk

No matter what I do I can't seem to change icon as well as gtk theme. My question is not a duplicate of

[Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)

because the solution doesnot work.

I have tried:

`gnome-tweak-tool`

`dconf-editor`

but both donot work.

[image]

Comment: That looks like the default GNOME theme there...something's pretty messed up. Was it always like this, or after you made some sort of change?

Comment: Everything was ok the last time, this morning when the computer was on I was greeted with this theme. I haven't changed anything

Answer (score 1):

i have too this problem. I used command

`gnome-tweak-tool`

than my computer freezed, then after a restart all was normal.