# Missing Unity after upgrade

Tags: unity, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unity doesn’t load, no Launcher, no Dash appears](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17381/unity-doesnt-load-no-launcher-no-dash-appears)

Ubuntu was working fine.
I upgraded to 11.1.
The Launcher is no longer visible, nor does moving the cursor to the left window margin work, nor does Alt-F2 help, etc.
However, when I login as GUEST, the Unity interface appears to be correct and as expected
All this leads me to believe that the problem is due to a (probable) config option.

However, at this time, I am trying to learn Ubuntu and am quite unfamiliar with the system and all associated jargon, so I need a very simple, step by step explanation. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds as if you have an incompatible or corrupt gnome setting. Sometimes the easiest thing to do is to re-create your home directory. I gave step-by-step instructions on how to do this in this question http://askubuntu.com/questions/87057/gnome-settings-daemon-not-starting-when-i-login/87069 please give it a try.