# How do I reset the ubuntu icon theme?

Tags: icons, themes

It appears my icon theme is busted.  I've been using it like this since April (11.04) upgrade, although I can't remember exactly how I got into this predicament.

How can I reset the ubuntu icon theme?  Which packages do I need to fix?

[image: folder icons]

[image: Desktop]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While searching through the this site, I found other people with similar problems.  I first attributed it to gnome-settings-daemon  not starting at the correct time, so I tried the fix listed here:

https://askubuntu.com/a/21901/37438

This did not fix the issue, but if I were to kill/relaunch `gnome-settings-daemon` then i would get the gnome theme back.

A little more digging, and web searching led me to remove my `.config/monitors.xml` file, due to a message on login that my monitors configuration was not being properly set.

I removed the xml file and everything works fine now.  No more default gnome icons :D

https://askubuntu.com/a/65538/37438