# My system loads before the themes

Tags: themes, ssd

I'm using ubuntu with a SSD. The only problem so far is that my system boots so fast that the themes aren't loaded. 
I already tried the tip on the first answer of this topic ([Desktop forgets theme?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/21305/desktop-forgets-theme)), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try add `sleep 10;` instead of 2 in the answer of the link you posted and see if that fixes it (maybe this is a different problem).

Comment: what theme? Do you mean desktop Environment, such as unity? can you post a picture?

Answer (score 0):

In my particular case i needed to change things up a bit. Changed that 3rd and 7th line from:

`pid=$(pgrep gnome-settings-)`

to:

`pid=$(pgrep gnome-tweak-)`

obviously it depends on what is responsible for loading the themes

to find your individual task that is responsible for that you may try:

`pid=$(pgrep gnome) && for i in $pid; do ps -p $i -o comm=; done`

most likely ist one of these tasks you get as output of that command.   ;)